# How to Maintain single copy of List among st all threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

```
class A implements Callable{

 List result     // want to share this List amongst thread and their function call

 public Search  call() {

 List<Job>  Jobs = api. Jobs(a,b,c);  // Multiple threads 

    }
 }


class API{
         public void jobs(a,b,c){
              // want to access the  A.Result and populate the result
         }
}
```

How can i share an array List amogst all threds, I dont want to use the Static , 
as it will keep accumilating the result every time it runs ,
Is Thread Local is a good choice over here ?

Trying to avoid an extra object and its respective getters / setters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ever you have right now is thread shared list. All threads operating on this object
(assuming only one instance of this object exists) share same list unless you synchronize.

Comment: glad it helped you. Enjoy programming.

Comment: @thinksteep "share the same list unless you synchronize". I am trying to understand what you mean here actually. Even if you synchronize the list IS STILL GOING TO BE SHARED, but (assuming you do it correctly) you will share it in a Thread-Safe way

Comment: @Eugene: That is exactly what I meant. If you synchronize, it is thread safe (but it seems OP doesn't need that), so I guess what ever he has right now will work non-thread safeway of sharing.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have your answer, but I did not understand the answer or the question, thus need to ask. So, you problem looks like this? You have a bunch of Callables that will perform some work on a SINGLE list, thus this list is shared among Threads? Then you need to make this List Thread Safe, and making a List of Objects Thread Safe is not that trivial (on your own), unless you use something already given by Java